# Mongo query with multiple filters on same attribute doesn't work with JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm new to mongoDb and created a query that fulfills my functional requirements:

```
db.collection.find( 
{
    "typeD": "ABC"
    , "typeT": {$size: 2}
    , "typeT": { $all: ["def", "abc"] }
    , "typeC": { $size: 3}
    , "typeC": { $all: ["pdf", "video", "png"] }
    , "properties": {$size: 3}
    ,"properties": 
    {
        $all: 
        [
          {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName1", "value": "proName1_value"} } 
        , {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName2", "value": "proName2_value"} } 
        , {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName3", "value": "proName3_value"} } 
        ]
    }   
);
```

I want to find the documents that exactly contains the elements provided by the arrays - as a fixed order of the elements inside arrays cannot be assumed, I've chosen the $all operator and to ensure exact matching I added to additional restriction with the $size.

Above query can be executed on mongo shell without any problems.

While trying to execute this statement with java by using mongoTemplate, I get some problems:

```
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(queryString);
CollectionEntity existingCmc = this.mongoTemplate.find(query, CollectionEntity.class);
```

After the first java line, query.toString() provides:

```
db.collection.find( 
{
    "typeD": "ABC"
    , "typeT": { $all: ["def", "abc"] }
    , "typeC": { $all: ["pdf", "video", "png"] }
    ,"properties": 
    {
        $all: 
        [
          {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName1", "value": "proName1_value"} } 
        , {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName2", "value": "proName2_value"} } 
        , {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName3", "value": "proName3_value"} } 
        ]
    }   
);
```

How can I execute the query that fulfills all of my requirements?
Can I rewrite the query so that one "single condition per attribute" is in the query?
How can I tell mongoTemplate, not to "overwrite" the previous condition for this attribute?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `{"typeC": { $size: 3, $all: ["pdf", "video", "png"] }}` to $and operators. You are overwriting the previous condition as well in shell query too.

Comment: Thx for your replay - it's working.

Haven't known that on mongoShell it is also overwritten

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB queries are actually Maps (Key-Value pairs).
Since you are defining 'properties' key two times which is why it is getting overridden.
Your desired query can be done using '$and' operator.

```
{ "$and": [ 
    { "properties": { "$size": 3 } }, 
    { "properties": { $all: 
        [
            {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName1", "value": "proName1_value"} }, 
            {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName2", "value": "proName2_value"} },
            {"$elemMatch": {"name": "propName3", "value": "proName3_value"} } 
        ] 
   } } 
] }
```